# PKCS#12 Keystore creation on Android device

Tags: android, bouncycastle, keystore, pfx, android-keystore

I'm currently developing an Android app that generates an RSA key pair, builds and sends an PKCS#10 certification request to one CA, waits for the CA's response (which contains the certificate-chain including the issued for the end-entity), and then builds the PKCS#12 KeyStore to be installed within the Android KeyStore.

I just show you below some piece of code:

```
// It removes Android-BC
Security.removeProvider("BC");
// I've tried with SpongyCastle but it also fails.
// I've previously imported BC jars.
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()); 
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12","BC");
ks.load(null);

// KeyPair generated by RSA with BC, and certificates obtained from CA.
PrivateKey prvK;
Certificate eeCert, caCert;

PKCS12BagAttributeCarrier caCertBagAttr = 
   (PKCS12BagAttributeCarrier) caCert;
caCertBagAttr.setBagAttribute(
   PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_friendlyName,
   new DERBMPString("CA"));

PKCS12BagAttributeCarrier certBagAttr =
   (PKCS12BagAttributeCarrier) eeCert;
certBagAttr.setBagAttribute(
   PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_friendlyName,
   new DERBMPString("EE Certificate"));
certBagAttr.setBagAttribute(
   PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_localKeyId,
   new SubjectKeyIdentifierStructure(eeCert.getPublicKey()));

Certificate[] chain = new Certificate[2];
chain[1] = caCert;
chain[0] = eeCert;

PKCS12BagAttributeCarrier privBagAttr = 
   (PKCS12BagAttributeCarrier) prvK;
privBagAttr.setBagAttribute(
   PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_friendlyName,
   new DERBMPString("EE Certificate Key"));
privBagAttr.setBagAttribute(
   PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_localKeyId,
   new SubjectKeyIdentifierStructure(eeCert.getPublicKey()));

// Finally, keystore is saved to file.
ks.setKeyEntry("P12", prvK, null, chain);
saveP12File(ks);
```

The thing is that everything is working OK when I run it on my Windows PC (BouncyCastle 1.49), but that PKCS#12 file created when I run it on Android cannot be used on SSL handshake or signing because Logcat says that it doesn't have any associated PrivateKey.

If I print the full content of the KeyStore on Java after loading the file, it seems that everything is right, but when I use on Android Browser or when I take it and install on Windows, its private key can't be used.

Same code on Android and PC, same version of BC, PKCS#12 doesn't seem to be malformed.

Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I have built a servlet that generates an RSA Key Pair and sends back to my app in PEM format.
All seems work OK:

- I can generate a valid (encrypting with public and decrypting test works good) RSA keypair either on Android device or through the external servlet.
- I receive both CA and EE certificates from the CA.
- I'm able to build a "valid" PKCS12 (I called it valid because it can be read by Android, Windows)

But:

- I'm not able to open an SSL channel using the EE certificate as client-certificate for handshake. Either on Windows or Android.

I have uploaded to my Dropbox:

1. [CA certificate](https://db.tt/ro3Ug4Rm)
2. [EE certificate issued by the CA](https://db.tt/8AridrmI)
3. [Private Key for the EE certificate](https://db.tt/B9m518Bt)
4. [Public Key for the EE certificate](https://db.tt/4mTJbTBt)
5. [PKCS12 created on Android](https://db.tt/mrUZM5SL)
6. [Java Android Code](https://db.tt/wG5iNzL2)

Tested against Tomcat with empty trustStore (doesnt' matter which CA issued client-certificate) unsuccessfully.

Does anybody see something that could explain it?

Comment: What if you produce two key stores one on PC and another on a handset and then try binary diff on the resulting files?

Comment: Doing what you're saying I've discovered that the problem was not PKCS#12 creation. It was RSA key pair generation. I don't know why, but  when I generate an RSA KeyPair on Android, save to PEM file, and then load on Java PC app, crtCoefficients are different.
Does anybody know why?

Comment: Could you show the code demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I've added some new details to my question...

Comment: Problem solved. I was creating PKCS#12 keystore with wrong PrivateKey. Neither BC nor Android shows failure message.
Thank you divanov for your help.

Comment: Not at all. This is type of problem I wouldn't be able to solve.